# How to make CUDA 8 work on Visual Studio 2015 update 3 with CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, cmake

I am having trouble even to compile the simplest code for CUDA 8 and Visual Studio 2015 update 3.

CUDASample.cuh

```
class CUDASample {
 public:
  CUDASample();
  ~CUDASample();
};
```

CUDASample.cu

```
#include "CUDASample.cuh"

CUDASample::CUDASample() {
}

CUDASample::~CUDASample(){
}
```

I am getting compilation errors like

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(63): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(64): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(76): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(98): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(118): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(125): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(126): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(137): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(144): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(161): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(170): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(171): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(180): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(188): error : unknown attribute "guard"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(189): error : unknown attribute "guard"
```

I am pretty sure it's a CUDA problem because if I change the source file extension to "cpp" and header extension to "h" everything works as usual. How can I solve this?

EDIT:

The commandline shown in properties -> Linker -> Command Line is

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\David\Desktop\sample\build\bin\Release\cudasample.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:/Users/David/Desktop/sample/build/bin/Release/cudasample.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64\cudart_static.lib" /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/David/Desktop/sample/build/lib/Release/cudasample.lib" /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\Users\David\Desktop\sample\build\bin\Release\cudasample.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"cudasample.dir\Release\cudasample.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

EDIT:

As Robert mentioned, since I am able to compile the cuda samples successfully, the problem might be related to cmake configuration. Below is the CMakeLists I used which work for me when compiling on Visual Studio 2013 + CUDA 7.5.

```
project(cudasample)

set(PROJECT_SRCS
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/CUDASample.cu
)

set(PROJECT_INCS
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/CUDASample.cuh
)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

find_package( CUDA REQUIRED )
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52;")
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;")
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;")
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;")
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF)
  list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-std=c++11;")
endif()

cuda_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PROJECT_SRCS} ${PROJECT_INCS})
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is this observed with the final release version of CUDA 8.0 or the release candidate? What is the version number reported by `nvcc`? Can you add to your question the exact invocation of `nvcc` that led to these error messages?

Comment: @njuffa this is the final release version of CUDA 8, `nvcc --version` yields V8.0.44. The sln is generated by cmake, using the standard `find_package( CUDA REQUIRED )` and `cuda_add_library`

Comment: Many people don't use CMAKE, or might use a version different from yours. By posting the actual `nvcc` commandline produced you would increase the chances of others being able to reproduce and diagnose the issue you see.

Comment: Its almost certainly an issue of the combination of cmake and VS and CUDA.  If you can build and run CUDA sample projects, then CUDA 8 is working correctly with VS 2015 update 3.  Mentioning `cmake` up front in your question is a good idea, and also tagging your question with `cmake`

Comment: @RobertCrovella I made some progress on solving this problem, would love to get your input

Comment: whoever downvotes you better explain yourself, or show me how trivial it is to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I at least managed to get it to work. The root cause is the [sdl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx) compiler flag in my head CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /sdl")
```

So if I add in this line in the project CMakeLists.txt

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "/sdl" "/sdl-" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

it will compile sucessfully.

However it is still unclear to me why the sdl compiler flag will cause NVCC to fail in the combination of CUDA 8 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. Hopefully someone can come up with a better answer.